# Why does Figma automatically flatten my text?

Tags: figma

Figma keeps flattening all my text boxes! I have no idea why, I do not do anything with these text boxes except moving them around.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Your question doesn't have enough details. What do you mean by "flattening all my text boxes"? What are you seeing on-screen? Is the text still editable? Can you share a screen shot showing the problem, and that also includes your layers panel with all the layers expanded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be great if you sent a screenshot of your problem with text layers.
Based on the available information, this problem can arise from the following:

- **Sticky keys.** When pressing `MacOS: Command E, Windows: Ctrl E` text is converted to vector.
- **Bugs in Figma itself.** Recently, Figma often produces errors and bugs. If you have a similar problem, my advice is to close Figma, clear your cookies, and restart your computer. This should fix the issue.

If none of this helped, send a screenshot and we will try to figure it out more clearly.